# C# Regex substring should be at start and end but not in the middle

Tags: c#, regex

Let's consider `${` the opening tag and `}$` the closing tag. The opening tag should only occur at the start and the closing tag. The chars `{`,`}`,`$` are allowed as long as they do not form one of the tags: So `${Macro{Inner}}$` is allowed.

This is what I tried: `\$\{[^((\$\{)|(\}\$))]+\}\$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the curly's don't have to be balances, you might use

```
(?<!\S)\${[^{}]*(?>(?:(?<!\$){|}(?!\$))[^{}]*)*}\$(?!\S)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\${` match `${`
- `[^{}]*` Optionally repeat matching any char other than `{` and `}`
- `(?>` Atomic group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?<!\$){` Match `{` asserting not `{` to the left
    - `|` Or
    - `}(?!\$)` Match `}` asserting not `}` to the right
  - `)` Close non capture group
  - `[^{}]*` Optionally repeat matching any char other than `{` and `}`
- `)*` Close the atomic group and optionally repeat
- `}\$` Match `}$`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5c%24%7b%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c!%5c%24%29%7b%7c%7d%28%3f!%5c%24%29%29%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%29*%7d%5c%24%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=%24%7bMacro%7bInner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bInner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bI%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7bnner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%24%7bInner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bInner%7d%7d%24%7b%7d%24)

---

If the parenthesis should be balanced, you could use:

```
(?<!\S)\${(?>(?<!\$){(?<c>)|[^{}]+|}(?!\$)(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!))}\$(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29%5c%24%7b%28%3f%3e%28%3f%3c!%5c%24%29%7b%28%3f%3cc%3e%29%7c%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%2b%7c%7d%28%3f!%5c%24%29%28%3f%3c-c%3e%29%29*%28%3f%28c%29%28%3f!%29%29%7d%5c%24%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=%24%7bMacro%7bInner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bInner%7d%7b%7d%7b%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bInner%7d%7b%7d%7b%7d%24%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bI%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7b%7bnner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%24%7bInner%7d%7d%24%0d%0a%24%7bMa%24cro%7bInner%7d%7d%24%7b%7d%24)

Answer (score 1):

Don't need regex for this

```
s.StartsWith("${") && s.EndsWith("}$") && new[]{"${", "}$"}.All(x => x.IndexOf(x, 2, s.Length-4) == -1)
```

Why do I advocate not using a regex?

- go for the simple solution, not the perfect one;
- this code is more readable/self documenting
- it's not so a regex so complicated that you have to ask on SO to make it work
- you or the developer that replaces you has a more reasonable chance at maintaining it than a regex of the required complexity

Answer (score 1):

You have tried the pattern `[^((\$\{)|(\}\$))]+` to prevent `${` or `}$` being matched, but that is a misunderstanding of how [character groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#negative-character-group-) work.

`[^((\$\{)|(\}\$))]` means match a single character that is not a `(`, `$`, `{`, `)`, `|`, or `}`.

The following working regex is an example of how to use a [negative lookahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to avoid `${` or `}$` being matched:

```
\$\{(?:(?!\$\{|\}\$).)*\}\$
```

If you want to match across newlines use `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

(Although I have done so, it is not necessary to escape the `{` and `}` in the regex above because the regex engine can determine from the surrounding context that they should be interpreted as match the literal character.)